# Can You Specify the Property Name of a Foreign Object in LINQ

Tags: linq, object, foreign-keys, properties

Suppose that I have 2 tables:

[User]
 - UserID
 - Username

[Task]
 - TaskID
 - TaskName
 - TaskCreatedByUserID
 - TaskAssignedToUserID

In the [Task] table, both of the ***UserID fields are foreign keys to the [User] table.  So when I use the designer to create my LINQ models, I have access to 2 foreign [User] objects with property names: "User" and "User1".  I'd like to give them more precise, meaningful names like "TaskCreatedByUser" and "TaskAssignedToUser" .  I could, of course, go into the dbml.designer.cs file and change them, but then they will simply be overwritten the next time I have to alter the DB.  Another option is to create a redundant property, but that seems silly.  Is there a way to manually specify the foreign object property names in the designer (or otherwise) in a way that is persistent?

Comment: Also what language are you working in? C#?

Comment: The existence of .cs files would necessarily mean that I'm using c#, however the question is generic enough that it should not matter what language is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the designer, right click on the line that represents the association between the classes, and select properties.  You can change the name of the child-collection property on the parent and the name of the parent property on the child.

The changes will be saved in the Association element in the dbml.

Comment: Thank you very much David.  For anyone else needing to do this, here's a more precise set of instructions:  Right click on the arrowed-line representing the child/parent correlation.  In the properties pane in the bottom right, you will see "Child Property" and "Parent Property".  Depending on the one that you wish to rename, hit the + sign next to it and change the "Name" subfield.